# Why bootstrap.css must be in the same domain with the html when we use htmlshiv.js and respond.js to make IE7 compatible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html5shiv, respond.js

When I use html5shiv.js和respond.js to make bootstrap.css(version 3.0) compatible with IE7,8,

In index.html(http://same.domain.com/index.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://same.domain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

It works.

when I subsitute that with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://another.domain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

It doesn't work!

So I think html5shiv.js or responds.js will judge if the css is the same domain with the html, 
Now, My Question is if it's ture, what can I do because the css and the html is not the same domain in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reason is that browser will request the css and js simultaneously, so when the js executes, the css is possibly not ready.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, respond.js will not process css which is not in the same domain with html.